# Can't see why I'm getting Heroku h10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, heroku-postgres

Can someone help me identify why my heroku app isn't working when I try to go to it? Here's what the heroku logs --tail says. It's long, but there are errors and I'm not sure what to do. This just randomly happened just after updating a couple things on my heroku app. The app is my web dev portfolio that I'm working on because I just graduated bootcamp.

```
2020-03-11T01:24:01.506977+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
2020-03-11T01:24:01.506977+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
2020-03-11T01:24:01.506977+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
2020-03-11T01:24:01.506979+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
2020-03-11T01:24:01.506986+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2020-03-11T01:24:01.546644+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2020-03-11T01:24:01.617316+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-03-11T01:24:05.179533+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 18969 -e production`
2020-03-11T01:24:11.228470+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-03-11T01:24:11.211218+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091218+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091232+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.2.4.1 application starting in production
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091233+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091725+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require': /app/app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:25: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091781+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091782+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091784+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091801+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091801+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091803+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091819+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091820+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:378:in `block in require_or_load'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091822+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091838+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:in `block in loading'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091839+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in `exclusive'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091841+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091858+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091858+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:356:in `require_or_load'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091874+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:49:in `block in require_or_load'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091874+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:17:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091904+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:48:in `require_or_load'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091905+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:334:in `depend_on'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091908+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:86:in `depend_on'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091908+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:246:in `require_dependency'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091909+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:478:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091910+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:477:in `each'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091928+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:477:in `block in eager_load!'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091939+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `each'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091940+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `eager_load!'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091940+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:356:in `eager_load!'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091940+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `each'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091944+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091946+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091946+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091947+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.091947+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.092346+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093023+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093046+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093081+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093104+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093124+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093144+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093164+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093184+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093203+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093231+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093253+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093279+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093301+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093321+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093342+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093361+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093381+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093401+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093429+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:49:in `require_relative'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093457+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093478+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093498+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093518+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093537+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093557+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093577+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093597+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27:in `app'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093617+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093637+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:312:in `block in start'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093656+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:379:in `handle_profiling'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093675+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:311:in `start'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093695+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:53:in `start'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093714+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093734+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093753+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093773+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093793+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093812+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093831+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093851+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093870+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093894+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093915+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093934+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093955+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093974+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.093994+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.094014+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.094033+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.094064+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2020-03-11T01:24:11.143307+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2020-03-11T01:25:33.969950+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=portfolio-kw.herokuapp.com request_id=00a39c61-5240-42d5-96b3-27b97a02aa50 fwd="24.8.64.123" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2020-03-11T01:25:34.171206+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=portfolio-kw.herokuapp.com request_id=cf080724-67df-4823-a67b-424bbb07b2e3 fwd="24.8.64.123" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the logs, it said

```
/app/app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:25: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)
```

Please check the code of `app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb` to make sure you have proper syntax.
It could mean you missed an `end`, a `)`, a `}`,etc.

Comment: Lol thank you so much. Just took a second pair of eyes. That was the whole issue. My Heroku app is working. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem @Kyle I used to be in your shoes :) Hope you have a great career with Rails